# PHP creates image file but only works on local dev, not at the remote server

Tags: php, image, gd

I have a code that dinamically resizes an image and sends it to the browser.

But it doesn't work properly... only if I ask it to output the image to a file instead of the browser.

I don't think the problem is my code, because this problem *only occurs on the real server*; in my computer its working perfectly.

Code:

```
$img = $_GET['img'];

ini_set('allow_url_fopen', 'on');

$info = getimagesize($img);
header('Content-type: '.image_type_to_mime_type($info[2]));
Fotos::redimensiona($img, null, Fotos::MINIGAL_WIDTH, Fotos::MINIGAL_HEIGHT, false);
```

Fotos::redimensiona():

```
//[...] a whole bunch of code calculating dimensions, they just works
// $funcImage is like 'imagejpeg'/'imagepng'/'imagegif', depends on file
if ($arquivo) {
    $funcImage($thumb, "$final.$ext");
    return "$final.$ext";
}
else {
    $funcImage($thumb);
}
```

Remember: it **works** on local development, but doesn't on remote web server.

**[EDIT]**
if I comment the `header` line, the binary code is printed; and this code changes when i change the original image, as expected.
But with the `header` Firefox shows me the URL of the page (like `http://www.sabianoar.com.br/novosabia/inc/phpImg.php?img=awful_escaped_long_path.jpeg`), and if I do `CTRL+I` it tells me it is an JPEG of 0x0 size, and like 10kb.
Opera shows me an empty image, as it would do if I had placed an `<img>` with the wrong `src`, i.e.

**[EDIT2]**
EyeOfGnome says "Not a JPEG file: starts with 0xef 0xbb" when I try to save and then open the output (it saves to a .jpeg file normally).

Comment: What happens when it 'doesnt work properly'? Does it error out? No output? broken image?

Comment: take a look at the edit. =] i've just added this info...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code outputs [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte-order_mark) at the beginning. Open your code from remote web server and check (using hex editor, for example xxd) if it contains BOM before `<?php`. If BOM isn't in a file you're looking at, it might be in includes.

Some editors add BOM and apache outputs it. That's probably what breaks your images.

Answer (score 0):

Check the permissions of the image/directory where the image is located.

Comment: The folder is 777, and the JPEG, 666. Both are readable. And I forgot to say [i'll edit the question], but if I comment the `header` line, the binary code is printed; and this code changes when i change the original image.

Comment: Have you tried making the JPEG 777 as well? I don't know if it will work. I've experience the quirk some time ago.

Comment: Also, check the HTML source from the browser.

Comment: Makin the image 777 does the same thing. I think that there's no point on this because different images generate differente binary code. If the image wasn't being read, it would say 'hey, I don't have permissions to read this'. ty anyway =]<br />
And I can't read the source because it has an image content-type.
But I tried to return the image to a file, and I saw that the HTML is simply empty. So, when it outputs the image code, there's only the code.

Answer (score 0):

This probably isn't the cause, but why are you echoing the result of `Fotos::redimensional()`? The functions like `imagejpeg()` etc. all return a bool (not the image data) after outputting the image, so you will end up printing a '1' to the end of the image. I just tested this though and it doesn't seem to break jpeg images.

Comment: yes... this doesn't break 'cos it works on my pc. anyway, i stripped out the echo. =P but doesn't solve my problem =(

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried comparing your local machine to the server? Compare the output of phpinfo(); Are they different platforms?